# How do I know the name of a tmux session?

Tags: linux, tmux

Recently, I started using `tmux`. I find it nice, but I'm still having issues understanding this application. One of the basic questions I have is: How do I know (from the command line) what is the name of the `tmux` session I'm logged to? If I'm logged to some `tmux` session, it will tell me its name. But if I'm not logged to a `tmux` session, it will print either nothing or some sort of an error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The name of the session is stored in the [tmux](/questions/tagged/tmux) variable `#S`, to access it in a [terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal), you can do

```
tmux display-message -p "#S"
```

If you want to use it in `.tmux.conf`, it's simply `#S`. Note that the `-p` option will print the message on stdout, otherwise the message is displayed in the [tmux](/questions/tagged/tmux) status line.

If the above command is called inside a session, it returns the name of the session. If it is called outside any session, it still returns the name of the last still running session. I couldn't find a [tmux](/questions/tagged/tmux) command to check, if one is inside a session or not, so I had to come up with this work around:

```
tmux list-sessions | sed -n '/(attached)/s/:.*//p'
```

`tmux list-sessions` shows all sessions, if one is attached, it shows `(attached)` at the end. With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) we suppress all output (option `-n`) except where we find the keyword `(attached)`, at this line we cut away everyhing after a `:`, which leaves us with the name of the session. This works for me inside and outside a session, as opposed to `tmux display-message -p "#S"`.

Of course this works only if there is no `:` and no `(attached)` in the name of the session.

As commented by [Chris Johnsen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1107/chris-johnsen), a way to check if one is inside a [tmux](/questions/tagged/tmux) session is to see if its environment variable is set:

```
[[ -n "${TMUX+set}" ]] && tmux display-message -p "#S"
```

Comment: Even it looks correct, I have to admit it didn't work for me. I have two consoles, in one I have the `tmux` session and in the other I'm outside the `tmux` session. When I type in both of them the command `tmux display-message -p "#S"`, the same result is printed and the return value of both commands is the same.

Comment: I see the same behavior. Look at my updated answer for a work around.

Comment: You can probably just get away with checking for the TMUX environment variable (it is normally set for processes inside a session, and not set outside a session—this is not “fool proof”, since something might set or unset TMUX and confuse things, but it should be fairly reliable). In *ksh*, *bash*, *zsh*, et cetera: `[[ -n "${TMUX+set}" ]] && tmux display-message -p "#S"`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That is indeed a more elegant way and robust enough, I reckon. I added your comment in my answer.

Comment: What if I'm inside two tmux sessions with different names at the same time? Does this work?

Comment: `tmux display-message -p "#{session_name}"` is the longhand form of the first command mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/212714/how-to-find-which-tmux-session-a-process-belongs-to), using this post I understood that the one thing which distinguishes the `tmux` clients is the their `tty` but session names are `tmux` server property and is the same when we look at the session name from inside  or outside a `tmux` client. Next, we may use `tmux info | head` which displays the the pid and tty of the client and the pid of the server.

```
tmux info | grep $$ | grep -q `ps -p $$ -o tty=`
```

The following command return value is 0 if we are inside a `tmux` client or non zero if we are running outside a `tmux` client. If you are running it from a script, make sure you use ppid instead of $$ since the tty is associated with the shell process not the script you are running.

One easy way but less robust to know if we are inside or outside `tmux` client is by looking at the TERM environment variable. It appears that outside the client it says 'xterm' but inside it says 'screen'. However, I find the first way much better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a perl script; making it a shell script or shell script function is an exercise left to the reader.

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

if (exists $ENV{'TMUX'}) {
    # session ID is the last element
    # /tmp/1s/ffkjhk76sdgn/T/tmux-771/default,16772,8
    my($id) = $ENV{'TMUX'};
    $id =~ s{^.*,(\d+)$}{$1};

    # get session name
    my($cmd) = q(tmux ls -F "#{session_name}: #{session_id}");
    open(IN, "$cmd |") || die qq([ERROR] Cannot open pipe from "$cmd" - $!\n);

    while (<IN>) {
        chomp;

        if (m{(^.*):\s+\$$id$}) {
            print "Session name: <$1>\n";
            exit 0;
        }
    }

    print "Unable to determine TMUX session name\n";
    exit 1;
}
else {
    print "Not in a TMUX session\n";

    exit 1;
}
```

This produces the following output in a TMUX session:

```
<~> $ tmuxsessionname
Session name: <1>

<~> $ tmux rename-session "foobar"

<~> $ tmuxsessionname
Session name: <foobar>
```

Outside of a TMUX session it would produce the following:

```
<~> $ tmuxsessionname
Not in a TMUX session
```

You can ditch the `print` statements and just use the exit code if you want to use this in a shell script or something.